# Show JFrame in desire location

Tags: java, swing, jframe, system-tray

I working on an application in which i using a `SystemTray`. Every things is fine in my code. When i click the `SystemTray` icon it show my `jFrame` in given location. But i want to show my `jFrame` just below my `SystemTray` icon.
Is this possible. Please suggest some code for it. As i can show it in my OS(linux) by giving right coordinate but my code is get fail if i run this program in different OS or different screen size system.

Comment: *"..icon it show my `jFrame` in given location."*  It is `JFrame` (note caps) and who/what is giving the location?  Never mind answering, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (all the answers we need).

Comment: Sir, I so sorry if my question heart you at lot.

Comment: Let i explain my question and what i want. Sir in my application i have a  `JFrame` which open in my given coordinate by using  `SetLocation( x , y);`. But i want to show this  `JFrame` just below of my  `SystemTray` icon. And please forgive my grammatical mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible to get the SystemTray icon coordinates on the screen using Swing. Another workaround would be to capture the mouse location when the tray icon is clicked.

```
Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
int mouseX = (int) p.getX();
int mouseY = (int) p.getY();
```

Keep in mind that this solution will not help you if you plan to navigate to the tray icon using your keyboard.